# firefox bookmarks folder path

Tags: firefox

How I can find path to bookmarks folder in firefox. My disk is pluged via USB as an external hard disk and I want to find my bookmarks and save them on my notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set: 
(show hidden files and folders) and then go to:

E:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ls6pqqyi.default\bookmarkbackups
inside json file is bookmarks address. Use Ctrl+F to find.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the actual folder where it stores. But I can give an idea to solve your problem.
There is one tool called "MozBackup.exe". You can use this tool to store all your firefox browser related information on it. Ofcourse you can restore it again using the same too.

Answer (score 0):

All bookmarks are stored in a file named "places.sqlite".

In order to reach to the file go to following path:

> C:\Users[YOUR_USER]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles[PROFILE_FOLDER]\places.sqlite